# OnTriggerEnter with tags

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have got some triggers and I want them dependant on tags. This is what I have so far:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{



    Destroy(gameObject);

}
```

I want to check to see if the gameobject triggering it has a certain tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is your friend!

Use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html)

the example is more or less exactly your code

> ```
> void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
> {
>     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
>     {
>         Destroy(other.gameObject);
>     }
> }
> ```